# what is the reason for my syntax error in stored procedure mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

```
  DELIMITER //           
                  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CleanupBackupRepositories ()
                  MODIFIES SQL DATA
   DELETE HISTORY
     FROM BackupRepositories
 BEFORE SYSTEM_TIME DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1YEAR);
//
DELIMITER;
```

i am trying to delete old history from this table but i get an syntax error on the line :
BEFORE SYSTEM_TIME DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1YEAR);
every example i have checked tells me to do it like this? thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Is it the missing space between `1YEAR`? You also might want to use `DATE_SUB` as `DATE_ADD` results in `2022-08-12`, not `2020-08-12` .

Comment: okay! that was it ... omg have i been searching so long for this typo! how do i mark your comment ? btw thanks for the tip!!

Comment: I'll just copy-paste it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing space between `1YEAR`.

You also might want to use `DATE_SUB` as `DATE_ADD` results in `2022-08-12`, not `2020-08-12`. The way it is now, it would effectively wipe out all the history.